# IIS/ASP.NET: How to manage the (partial) output cache?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, cache

I'm working on adding a lot of partial output caching to a quite traffic heavy site. How can I administrate this?

For example is there any way to clear the cache if somethings goes wrong?

Does a server reboot flush the output cache?

I'm running Asp 3.5 on IIS6. Microsoft Server 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a GUI in IIS for resetting the cache specifically, but any time the application pool or AppDomain restarts, it will flush the cache.

You can restart the application pool in IIS. Or you can touch (re-save the file without any changes) the web.config file to restart the AppDomain.